# Product of large number with a very small number returns zero because Mathematica sets the very small number equal to zero

Tags: special-functions, numerical-value, approximation

I have a product `Exp[-I*Pi*x]*BesselK[-1, 2.43*Ix]`. Now, `Exp[-I*Pi*x]` grows larger and larger as $x$ increases for imaginary large values, while `BesselK[-1, 2.43*Ix]` decreases. At a particular large imaginary value of $x$, while the product is finite, `Exp[-I*Pi*x]` is very large while `BesselK[-1, 2.43*Ix]` is around $10^{-300}$ and Mathematica sets the latter to be equal to zero, which makes the product become equal to zero.

Is there a way to tell Mathematica not to do this?

The exact input is:

```
Exp[-I*Pi*x]*BesselK[-1, 2.43*I*x] /. x -> I*290 // N
```

This returns `-1.97747*10^88 - 2.456351670414645*10^700`I
If I write:     `Exp[-I*Pi*x]*BesselK[-1, 2.43*I*x] /. x -> I*291 // N`
then it returns `0. - 6.445487767605421*10^702 I`
So, there is a jump in the transition of `x=290` to `x=291`

Comment: What is the exact input that produces what? Do you really mean `ix` or rather `I x`?

Comment: What is `ix`? Somthing like `I x`?

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant Ix. I will edit the question.

Comment: What is "some number"?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I try some values of the above product because I need it to work for a large range of values of $x$.

Comment: Really, give an example. It is important to know the precision of the number.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher OK, I will edit the answer in a couple of minutes. Thank for the input

Comment: Can't reproduce this.

Comment: My results is

$ 3.25745*10^{42} - 8.60218*10^{41} I $

Comment: @SlepeckyMamut Sorry, I tried to reproduce a simpler example of what I had and ended up giving a wrong example. I edited the answer. I am sincerely sorry for this.

Comment: @Jens See my above comment. So sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan `Exp[-I*Pi*x]*BesselK[-1, 2.43*I*x] /. x -> I*290 // N` returns `-3.95494*10^88 - 2.456351670414645*10^700 I` on my machine while `Exp[-I*Pi*x]*BesselK[-1, 2.43*I*x] /. x -> I*291 // N` returns `-8.04327*10^88 - 6.445487767605421*10^702 I`. (I ran it in version Mma 11.3 on macOS.) Please make sure that your kernel is clean. Giving you Mathematica version and the operating system might also be a good idea.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher My version is 10.2. I also run it on Windows 10. I don't seem to get the result that you get. What about if you bump up x to larger values? Would your software still not set it to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`arbitrary precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html) rather than machine precision.

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

Exp[x]*BesselK[-1, I x] /. x -> I*290.`20

(* 5.3594789574372585*10^124 - 3.6455728547082617*10^124 I *)

Exp[x]*BesselK[-1, I x] /. x -> I*290 // N[#, 20] &

(* 5.3594789574372584720*10^124 - 3.6455728547082616665*10^124 I *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
expr = Exp[-I Pi x]*BesselK[-1, I x] /. x -> I*706 // N[#, 650] &;

expr // NumberForm[#, 6] &
```

[image]

Comment: Exp[-I*Pi*x]*BesselK[-1, 2.43*I*x] /. x -> I*291 // N[#, 20] &    There still exists a jump between 290 and 291.

Comment: That's because you used the machine number 2.43. Calculations with machine numbers yield machine numbers without any precision tracking. Raising the precision to 20 afterward does nothing useful.

Comment: @JohnDoty If you put $1$ at the place of $2.43$, you get the jump between 705I and 705 I. But, that is by using //N and not //N[#,20]. (There seems to be a problem in my version with //N[#,20])

Comment: Yes. `//N` takes you explicitly into the domain of machine numbers. So, implicitly, does `2.43`. With machine numbers you get speed without precision control. But `1` is exact, and `//N[#,20]` gives you a controlled precision result.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan - You need to include the `&` after the `//N[#,20]` i.e., `//N[#,20]&` See [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon Okay, I figured this out. I need to put more than 20 significant digits. If I put something like `Exp[-IPix]*BesselK[-1, Ix] /. x -> I*706 // N[#, 200] &` then it gives back that the are not enough significant digits to display for the real part. So, I must use something like `Exp[-IPix]*BesselK[-1, Ix] /. x -> I*706 // N[#, 650] &`. This way, the real part is considered "significant enough" but the imaginary part is returned in too many digits that it fills the screen. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @TheQuantumMan - `expr // NumberForm[#, 6] &`

Comment: @BobHanlon i really appreciate your help, but this again gives zero for the real part when I actually try to perform calculations because say `BesselK[1,-706]` is nearly equal to zero

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @theorist - Don't know; but the workaround is to use `FunctionExpand`: `Exp[-I*Pi*x]*BesselK[-1, 243/100*I*x] /. x -> I*290 // 
  FunctionExpand // N[#, 20] &`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
fn[x_] := Exp[-I*Pi*x]*BesselK[-1, 243/100*I*x]

fn[I*290`20]
(*-1.9774702657848900*10^88 - 2.4563516704146749*10^700 I*)

fn[I*291`20]
(*-4.0216330025933670*10^88 - 6.445487767605888*10^702 I*)

fn[I*706`20]
(*-4.610286369132861*10^216 - 6.271805320261515*10^1706 I*)
```