# How to prevent Mathematica rounding extremely small numbers to zero?

Tags: numerics, evaluation, special-functions

I have a function that, while the maths itself is unimportant, at certain values it results in a very large number multiplying a very small number. E.g. 10^450000 * 10^-449998. As you can see, this should output the more-sensible number 10^2. However Mathematica is rounding the small number to zero thus the whole calculation breaks down. How can I prevent this? I've played with MinNumber and MachinePrecision but neither seem to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Including the equation as requested:

$\exp[\cfrac{\omega^2}{\sigma^2}] BesselK[1,\cfrac{\sqrt(\cfrac{\omega}{\sigma^2})}{\sqrt(\cfrac{\sigma^2}{\omega^3})}]$

Equation breaks down for $\sigma<0.01*\omega$ and generally unreliable below $\sigma<0.04*\omega$

Edit2: And the Mathematica code!

```
bessktot[ω0_, σ_] := BesselK[1, Sqrt[ω0/σ^2]/Sqrt[σ^2/ω0^3]]
expcalctot[ω0_, σ_] := E^(ω0^2/σ^2);
ω0 = 2 \[Pi] 10^12;
σ[BWpc_] := BWpc/100 ω0;
σt = σ[1]
bessktot[ω0, σt]
expcalctot[ω0, σt]
expcalctot[ω0, σt]*bessktot[ω0, σt]
```

Edit3: Thanks Bob Hanlon, (I can't comment back on your answer yet). Your answer works for certain values input to the bessel. The problem appears to be even more fundamental than I realised. It appears Mathematica can't calculate non-integer $BesselK[1,x]$ functions when $x>741$. Is there a way around this?

Comment: On my machine, even with machine precision exponents, `10^45000000000000.*10^-44999999999998.` outputs `1.0 * 10^2` from a fresh startup. It should only start rounding to 0 if it runs out of precision during the calculation, one of the intermediate functions does not handle arbitrary precision arithmetic (not common, but some don't), if it's explicitly told to start rounding somewhere, or if something is actually multiplied by 0. We will need a bit more code to diagnose what's actually going on, so please consider posting your function.

Comment: @eyorblade `0^45000000000000.` is certainly no a machine precision number: `Precision[110^45000000000000.]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher In `a_^b_`, the `b` is machine precision, is it not? The resulting value is not, obviously, because there's any precision tracking at all. I suspect _Mathematica_ knows what it's doing here, in that with exact `a` the precision isn't lost very quickly at all, but the exponent isn't the source of the uncertainty in this case.

Comment: If the issue is with *Mathematica* code, please post the *Mathematica* code rather than a LaTeX representation.

Comment: You may wish to look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180379 (and the comment on `FunctionExpand` above it) and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180327

Comment: The result is `E^10000 BesselK[1, 10000]`and `E^10000 BesselK[1, 10000]//N` gives 0.0125336113513.  Do you get something different?

Comment: Currently looking at those pages, Thanks eyorble. Although for ```E^10000 BesselK[1, 10000] // N``` I get "0."

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* and operating system are you using?  I got the non-zero result using *Mathematica* 10.4 and Windows 10.

Comment: "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" on Windows 10 x64

Comment: @Andrew  When I approved your edit, I notice that you have two different accounts, both with the same name.  I do not know how that happened, but you should be able to combine the two.  Then, you will not need the approval of others to edit your own question.

Comment: You could try to add logarithms instead of multiplying crazy-small/big numbers.

Answer (score 9):

There was a change in handling underflow in later versions.

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

bessktot[ω0_, σ_] := 
  BesselK[1, Sqrt[ω0/σ^2]/Sqrt[σ^2/ω0^3]];
expcalctot[ω0_, σ_] := E^(ω0^2/σ^2);
ω0 = 2 π 10^12;
σ[BWpc_] := BWpc/100 ω0;
σt = σ[1];
```

MachinePrecision is insufficient,

```
(expr = expcalctot[ω0, σt]*bessktot[ω0, σt]) // N

(* 0. *)
```

Use [`arbitrary precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionNumbers.html)

```
expr // N[#, $MachinePrecision] &

(* 0.01253361135127051 *)

expr // N[#, 20] &

(* 0.012533611351270505734 *)
```

**EDIT:** For large input to [`BesselK`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselK.html) you need to control the precision of the input.

```
BesselK[1, #] & /@ {801., 801.`20, SetPrecision[801., 20]}

(* {0., 5.9781508629496523*10^-350, 5.9781508629496523*10^-350} *)
```

Comment: Note that, although ``801.`20`` and `SetPrecision[801., 20]` are equivalent, in general these approaches can give different results for numeric literals. E.g. ``1.1`20 != SetPrecision[1.1, 20]``. That's because in the latter case `1.1` is first converted to a machine number then extended the equivalent arbitrary-precision value, while ``1.1`20`` becomes arbitrary-precision directly at the parsing stage.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to go about this is to use the [representation of your function in terms of Meijer $G$](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/26/02/02/0002/):

```
With[{ω = N[2 π 1*^12], σ = N[2 π 1*^12]/100},
     -MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{-1, 1}, {}}, 2 (ω/σ)^2]/Sqrt[π]]
   0.012533611351270506
```

Other computing environments, however, usually provide an exponentially-scaled modified Bessel function (e.g. [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/besselk.html#mw_4718d9b5-eb15-44e5-a3a0-c5c9775e06a9)) because of numerical problems like these; since *Mathematica* does not implement these convenient functions, we have to either use arbitrary precision, or make do.

Comment: (That's it for me for now, Wolfram One tends to not work right if the Internet connection is spotty.)

Comment: great to see you around again

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only come sporadically depending on whether I can go to an Internet café, but I hope I can be regular again soon.